# Group By specified numbers of ordered rows

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by, limit

I have such table in my MySQL database:

```
---------------------------
|fid | price | date       |
---------------------------
|  1 | 1.23  | 2011-08-11 |
|  1 | 1.43  | 2011-08-12 |
|  1 | 1.54  | 2011-08-13 |
|  1 | 1.29  | 2011-08-14 |
|  1 | 1.60  | 2011-08-15 |
|  1 | 1.80  | 2011-08-16 |
```

`fid` - this is the product id
`price` - this is the price of the product in specified day

I want to calculate average price of the product `fid=1`. I want to calculate the average price of first `n=3` rows ordered by date for specified `fid`, and then calculate average price for another 3 rows ordered by date.

How can I group first 3 rows and calculate avg and then group next 3 rows and calculate avg. Before calculation I need to sort the rows by date and then group `n` rows.

If `n=3` this should return such result:

```
--------------
|fid | price |
--------------
|  1 | 1.40  | 2011-08-11 -> 2011-08-13 - average price for 3 days
|  1 | 1.56  | 2011-08-14 -> 2011-08-16 - average price for 3 days
```

How can I create SQL Query to do such calculations?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unluckily mysql doesn't offer analytic functions like oracle,mssql and postgres do. So you have to play with variables to reach your goal.

```
create table mytest (
id int not null auto_increment primary key,
fid int,
price decimal(4,2),
fdate date
) engine = myisam;

insert into mytest (fid,price,fdate)
values 
(1,1.23,'2011-08-11'),
(1,1.43,'2011-08-12'),
(1,1.54,'2011-08-13'),
(1,1.29,'2011-08-14'),
(1,1.60,'2011-08-15'),
(1,1.80,'2011-08-16');


select 
concat_ws('/',min(fdate),max(fdate)) as rng,
format(avg(price),2) as average from (
select *,@riga:=@riga+1 as riga
    from mytest,(select @riga:=0) as r order by fdate
     ) as t
group by ceil(riga/3);


+-----------------------+---------+
| rng                   | average |
+-----------------------+---------+
| 2011-08-11/2011-08-13 | 1.40    |
| 2011-08-14/2011-08-16 | 1.56    |
+-----------------------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

Comment: This is great. I didn't know where to declare variable. Now I see that is declared in subquery by select @riga:=0. Great answer. Thank You very much

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could use

```
GROUP BY FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date)/(60*60*24*3))
```

= convert to secounds, divide by secounds for 3 days, and round down

Comment: what if there is a "hole" in the dates, i.e. some day is missing?

Comment: then it calculates the average on the 2 existin prices of the 3 (real) days

Comment: exactly, but this is not what the asker wanted, AFAIK (and if the dates are more sparse, it will just average 1 price)

Answer (score 0):

```
select fid, avg(price), min(date), max(date)
from
    (select floor((@rownum := @rownum + 1)/3) as `rank`,  prices.*
    from prices, (SELECT @rownum:=-1) as r
    order by date) as t
group by rank
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT AVG( price ) FROM my_table
    GROUP BY ( date - ( SELECT MIN( date ) FROM my_table WHERE fid = 1 ) ) DIV 3
    WHERE fid = 1
```

Comment: what if there is a "hole" in the dates, i.e. some day is missing?

Comment: @Tomas When there is a "hole" the value of the missing date will be igonred.

Comment: but your solution will not group 3 consecutive dates then, because you group dates by their value.